# Mac kills WiFi router whenever it tries to connect to it

Tags: wireless-networking, router, mac

So this is a bit weird. I have a main WiFi router downstairs and a WiFi extender in my office. Whenever I wake my Mac [1] (and its Wifi is on) it kills the extender and it takes an unusual amount of time for it get back online.

Turning off/on the extender in this situation doesn't seem to work. Turning the Mac's WiFi off doesn't immediately resolve the problem either.

The downstairs router doesn't seem to be affected.

The extender's network is named differently than the main one. I believe the extender connects to the internet via the power outlet.

How do I go about diagnosing this?

---

[1] Macbook Air 2013

Comment: Did you check for IP address conflicts? (2 devices having the same IP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a half answer. It turns out the problem happens when the laptop is plugged into the wall, regardless of its WiFi status. This leads me to believe that it's an issue with the power supply or the electrical work in the room. Since the extender connects to the internet via the mains, there must be some sort of shenanigans going there.

As such, I don't think this question is suitable for this particular Stack Exchange.